# Old iPhone 4S won't accept my Apple ID when trying to reset it for a trade-in. Why?

Tags: apple-id

I recently deactivated my old iPhone 4S after buying a new phone. I want to trade it in, so I'm trying to reset it, but it won't accept my Apple ID.

Is it because it's been deactivated? How can I wipe it?

Comment: When you say it "won't accept your Apple ID", what steps are you taking and where exactly is the problem occurring?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to "Find my iphone" and trying to turn it off. When prompted for my apple ID, I type it in and enter it, and it says my iphone appleID cannot be verified. Also, I just went to Verizon, my carrier, and they actually reactivated this iPhone so that I could reset it, and even then it wouldn't accept my apple ID. I know I'm typing it in correctly and that it works, because when I went to apple to ask for help (which I can't really get since I don't have a tech support deal with them) I had to enter it there. It worked, no problem. So what do you think?

Comment: Could you just restore your iPhone? If you're just trading it in, a restored device should be fine.

Comment: Yes! Finally, after talking to three different Apple Support people throughout the course of the day (I figured a way around buying a support contract, hehehe...), that is what they finally had me do. Thank you. And yes, that worked, if anyone else is in this same situation. Though the AppleCare people said they hadn't seen this before, so I doubt many people will have to deal with this.

Comment: i feel like after i restored a phone with find my phone that it then wouldn't let me set it up again until i put in the info.  is this not the case for you?  but i had the same situation where i couldn't disable it for unknown reasons, i verified pw on icloud.com etc.

Answer (score 1):

Sign into wifi and then try again! Had this problem for forever and the idea of turning on my wifi to verify my apple ID popped into my head and it worked! Best of luck.